# Encontrar a posição de uma letra usando FOR

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um projeto que é o seguinte.

O Programa pede ao usuário um texto e uma letra que vai ser procurada dentro desse texto e quero que ele me retorne a posição.

Ex.: Se colocar a palavra "Mesa" e eu quero procurar a letra "s" ele me volta a resposta de "3" que é a posição que se encontra a letra "s"

Estou Utilizando este código.

```
string Texto = "", Palavra = "", resposta = "";
int contador = 0;

Texto = txttexto.Text;
Palavra = txtpalavra.Text;

for (int i = 0; i < Texto.Length; i++)
{
    if (Texto.Contains(Palavra))
    {
        contador++;             
    }
}

txtresposta.Text = Convert.ToString(contador);
```

Comment: Mas qual é a sua duvida?

Comment: O Código não me retorna a posição da letra, eu queria que ele me retornasse a posição e ele me retorna a letra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem algumas coisas erradas aí, mas vou focar apenas no erro crucial da sua tarefa.

Este bloco de código

```
if (Texto.Contains(Palavra))
{
    contador++;             
}
```

verifica se a variável `Texto` contém o valor da variável `Palavra` (que deveria se chamar `letra`, certo?).

Vamos fazer um teste **de mesa** (desculpe, não pude evitar).

Cada linha da tabela abaixo representa um laço da repetição

```
i | Texto | Palavra | Texto.Contains(Palavra) | contador | 
- | ----- | ------- | ----------------------- | -------- |
0 | Mesa  | s       | true                    |    0     |
1 | Mesa  | s       | true                    |    1     |
2 | Mesa  | s       | true                    |    2     |
3 | Mesa  | s       | true                    |    3     |
```

Entendeu o problema?

O valor de `contador` sempre vai ser o índice da última letra da palavra.

---

A primeira coisa que você precisa ter em mente é que, em C#, uma `string` é uma cadeia de caracteres (para simplificar, um ***array* de `char`**). E, como toda coleção indexada em C#, o primeiro item está na posição 0. Portanto, a partir do momento que você souber o índice de uma letra, precisará incrementá-lo em 1 para apresentar para o usuário.

A maneira mais simples de resolver este problema é usando o método [`IndexOf`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof). Algo como:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string texto = "mesa", letra = "s";
    var pos = texto.IndexOf(letra) + 1;
    Console.WriteLine($"Encontrada a letra {letra} na palavra {texto} na posição {pos}");
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tYcdqJ)</sup>

Imagino que você esteja aprendendo e por isso fez usando o `for`, então aqui um código funcional com a mesma estrutura do seu código original:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string texto = "mesa"; 
    char letra = 's';

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < texto.Length; i++)
    {
        if (texto[i] == letra)
            break;            
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i + 1));
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pXDitJ)</sup>

Comment: Funcionou! obrigado, me ajudou muito.